# xsl:element + xsl:function = weirdness? (Saxon,Java)

Tags: xslt, xpath, xslt-2.0

I've been battling this XSL (Saxon/Java) code for several hours now, and still can't figure it. I narrowed the problem down to this snippet:

```
<xsl:function name="my:fff" >
  <xsl:element name="p0">
    <p1 aaa='AAA' />
  </xsl:element>
</xsl:function>

<xsl:function name="my:ggg">

  <xsl:variable name="v" select="my:fff()" />

  <!-- Debug messages -->
  <xsl:message>
    $v          '<xsl:sequence select="$v" />'
    $v/*        '<xsl:sequence select="$v/*" />'
    $v/*/@aaa   '<xsl:value-of select="$v/*/@aaa" />'
    $v/p0       '<xsl:sequence select="$v/p0" />'
  </xsl:message>
    ...
</xsl:function>
```

The output printed by the  in `my:ggg` is as follows:

```
  $v          '<p0><p1 aaa="AAA"/></p0>'
  $v/*        '<p1 aaa="AAA"/>'
  $v/*/@aaa   'AAA'
  $v/p0       ''
```

The first three lines are fine. But the fourth line which outputs an empty string is weird. I mean, if `$v` is `<p0><p1 aaa="AAA"/></po>` (as indicated in the first line) then why is it that `$v/p0` isn't `<p1 aaa="AAA"/>` ?

What am I missing?

Comment: `$v` is the element returned by `my:fff`, so it *is* the tag `<p0>` including children. `$v/p0` tries to select a `<p0>` as child of the tag in `$v`, which is empty as the tag `<p0>` selected by `$v` does not contain a `<p0>`.

Comment: @rsp - You should make this an answer, as it *is* the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your reasoning would be OK if the `my:fff()` function was returning a document node -- not an element (`p0` that itself doesn't have a `p0` child).

So, if you change the function to be the following:

```
 <xsl:function name="my:fff" as="document-node()" >
        <xsl:document>
         <xsl:element name="p0">
            <p1 aaa='AAA' />
         </xsl:element>
        </xsl:document>
 </xsl:function>
```

And the complete transformation would be:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
 xmlns:my="my:my">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

 <xsl:template match="/">
  <xsl:sequence select="my:ggg()"/>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:function name="my:fff" as="document-node()" >
        <xsl:document>
         <xsl:element name="p0">
            <p1 aaa='AAA' />
         </xsl:element>
        </xsl:document>
 </xsl:function>

 <xsl:function name="my:ggg">
    <xsl:variable name="v" select="my:fff()" />
    <!-- Debug messages -->
    <xsl:message>
         $v          '
        <xsl:sequence select="$v" />
        '     $v/*        '
        <xsl:sequence select="$v/*" />
        '     $v/*/@aaa   '
        <xsl:value-of select="$v/*/@aaa" />
        '     $v/p0       '
        <xsl:sequence select="$v/p0" />'
    </xsl:message>     ...
 </xsl:function>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**then applying this transformation on any XML document (not used), produces now the following debugging output**:

```
     $v          '<p0><p1 xmlns:my="my:my" aaa="AAA"/></p0>'
     $v/*        '<p0><p1 xmlns:my="my:my" aaa="AAA"/></p0>'
     $v/*/@aaa   ''
     $v/p0       '<p0><p1 xmlns:my="my:my" aaa="AAA"/></p0>'
```

which is probably what you want, with the exception of the `aaa` attribute, which needs to be accessed as: `$v/*/*/@aaa`

Answer (score 1):

`$v` is the element returned by `my:fff`, so it *is* the tag `<p0>` including children. `$v/p0` tries to select a `<p0>` as child of the tag in `$v`, which is empty as the tag `<p0>` selected by `$v` does not contain a `<p0>`.

Answer (score 1):

You would find it easier to diagnose this kind of problem if you made a habit of always declaring the argument and return types of a function. That would force you to think about what my:fff returns. In this case it's a (parentless) element node: you can declare the result as `as="element(p0)"`. It would then stick out much more clearly that a p0 element is unlikely to have any p0 children, so `my:fff()/p0` is probably wrong.